# Google closure compiler doesn't remove unreachable code marked with @define annotation

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

Why this code doesn't result in an empty string after compilation with SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS

```
/**
 * @define {boolean}
 */
var TEST = false;
(function() {
    if (TEST) {
        foo();
    }
})();
```

and instead I get the following?

```
var TEST=!1;(function(){TEST&&foo()})();
```

The `if` is unreachable but the closure compiler doesn't remove the code.
With "advanced optimizations" the result is what I expect (empty) but "simple optimizations" give the above result. Why this difference? The code will never be executed in both cases.

**EDIT**:
If I remove the closure, the `if` block is removed too. Why with closure this doesn't happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it would be removed if using "advanced optimizations"

Comment: Yes, but why using "simple optimizations" the code is not removed?

Comment: Well, because it's an optimization that is considered "advanced" :)

I'm not sure exactly how the simple/advanced split was determined, to be honest.

Comment: Simple optimizations only do local optimizations (only values within a function or expressions).  Global values are not moved, inlined, etc.   It is "simple" in that you don't need to conform to any particular coding style in order for it to work.  Advanced mode is different: if you don't export something the compiler tries to remove it. This can break code with external references to it.