# Remove warning on minified js by Google closure compiler

Tags: javascript, node.js, webstorm, minify, google-closure-compiler

I get warning after minifying js file with Google closure compiler. The warning appears at the top of the minified file and looks something like this;

```
test_chk.js:198: WARNING - unreachable code
        return;
        ^
```

Do I have to manually remove this warning from the minified file? How can I get closure compiler not to put these warnings on the minified file? Some of the warnings are for code that are legitimate that I want to leave there.

I am using node.js v4.6 on WebStorm 2016.2.3

EDIT: The closure compiler was run in this manner with the following arguments on Webstorm;

```
closure-compiler-v20160911.jar --compilation_level SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS --js $FileName$
```

Comment: In general you're likely to get some weird warnings from the Closure Compiler when trying to compile code that has already been compiled/minified, by the Closure Compiler or a similar tool.

Comment: Do I need to manually remove these weird warnings from every js file? This is tedious.

Comment: Something is wrong with your setup. Warnings and error messages should not be included in the output file. However you have not given enough information to diagnose the root cause.

Comment: Chad Killingsworth, Thanks for your comment. I have added more information to the question. Hope it is enough.

Comment: Chad Killingsworth, warnings are included by default. The compiler settings for warnings need to be set to QUIET.

Answer (score 3):

Use the following arguments on Webstorm for the Google closure compiler;

```
closure-compiler-v20160911.jar --warning_level QUIET --compilation_level SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS --js $FileName$
```

The key lies in suppressing the warning_level to QUIET.

There is another method without suppressing the warning_level to QUIET.

- Go to Settings->Tools->File Watchers->Edit Watcher ...
- Uncheck the box "Create output file from stdout"

Comment: This solves your problem only because it silences warnings. It's not a good solution. Warnings and errors are output via stderr and shouldn't be included.

Comment: Chad Killingsworth, I found another method that does not silence the warning. Answer has been updated.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell without seeing the code itself. Did you try closure options like discussed here:

- https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/issues/1222
- [Google closure compiler doesn't remove unreachable code marked with @define annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33241581/google-closure-compiler-doesnt-remove-unreachable-code-marked-with-define-anno)